# test web site setup on IIS6

Tags: windows-7, iis-6

I am working on a setup project that installs a web site on IIS6. I have Windows7 on my machine, and I can install IIS7 on it, but not IIS6 as far as I know. So what are the ways to test my setup project on IIS6? The free and legal ways (without any cracks) are prefered :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can install Windows Server 2003 on a Virtual PC, and they both appear to be free!

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=77f24c9d-b4b8-4f73-99e3-c66f80e415b6&displaylang=en

Haven't tested yet, but I think it will be fine, if the documentation doesn't lie:

*This is a preconfigured virtual machine contained within the Virtual Hard Disk (VHD) format. A virtualization product that supports the VHD format is required to use this virtual machine. Microsoft Virtual PC or Microsoft Virtual Server are provided for free and can be used with these VHD based virtual machines. Please refer to the system requirements section for more details.*

Answer (score 3):

Setup a Windows XP Pro virtual machine and install IIS6 on that.

http://www.virtualbox.org/

Comment: Yes, I am aware of virtual box, but even though it is free, WinXP isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way to do this is to have a remote connection to a machine that already has IIS6.